# How can I specify a different configuration for Vim based on the executable name?

Tags: vim

I am trying to open Vim with different configuration options depending on the executable file name. I intend to create a number of symbolic links to vim and I'd like to do something like this in my .vimrc

```
if execname == "vim2"
   " configuration here
endif
```

Is there a variable in Vim that holds the name of the executable file being run? Alternatively, is there another way I can have different configurations without having to keep more than one .vimrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the variable v:progname.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make each desired name to be an alias which first renames .vimrc.configX into .vimrc before calling vim

Comment: Yes, I can tweak it that way, but then I'd need to keep a different file for each configuration, I'd like to have a single valid .vimrc file.